how to escape double quote backslash in snowflake file format
My csv file has fields which in enclosed with double quotes and the fields are separated with |. For some of the fields i have below value in csv file:
|"\"Bremen \""|

I want to remove \" so after copy into the output should be saved as :
|"Bremen "|

Below in the file format command i tried but it didn't worked:
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT PO_PIPE
    type = 'CSV'    
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.ff' 
    skip_header = 1
    field_delimiter = '|'    
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"'
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
    null_if = ('\\N','NULL','Null','(null)','null','','\\n')
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE
    ESCAPE = '\\'
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH=FALSE
    COMPRESSION=GZIP;


The provided file format seems to work. For input.csv:
col|col2
"\"Bremen \""|1
"\"Test\""|2

Recreating:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col TEXT, b INT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT PO_PIPE
    type = 'CSV'    
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.ff' 
    skip_header = 1
    field_delimiter = '|'    
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"'
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
    null_if = ('\\N','NULL','Null','(null)','null','','\\n')
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE
    ESCAPE = '\\'
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH=FALSE;

-- place file into the stage
LIST @TESTSTAGE;
-- teststage/input.csv

COPY INTO PUBLIC.TAB
 FROM @TESTSTAGE/input.csv
 FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = 'PO_PIPE')
 FORCE = TRUE;

SELECT * FROM tab;

Output:


i am not sure why its failing for me then i think you use the same file format

i am getting error as Found character 'B' instead of field delimiter '|'

@Andrew Maybe some invisible characters are involved(?) You can open CSV in Notepad++ and check.

i have checked actually its complaining only at this point. Is there another workaround solution i can try ?
